# Adding points every X distance along a LineString

Tags: python, point, interpolation, shapely, linestring

I have a list of LineString coords:

```
 list = [(90, 170), (99.0, 159.0), (321.0, 159.0), (300, 146), (296, 23)]
```

which looks like this.
[image]

How to interpolate a point at every X distance along the line using Shapely?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is actually pretty easy.

Have a look at https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#object.interpolate

Sample code:

```
distance = 0 ## starting at length 0
add_distance = 10 ## eg interpoalte every 10 meter

while distance < line.length:
   new_point = line.interpolate(distance)
   distance += add_distance ## add more
```

You will have to convert that list of tuples into actual LineString:

```
list_of_points = [Point(tuple) for tuple in list]
line = LineString(list_of_points)
```